# «Незнаю» или «не знаю»?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, глаголы

Как писать правильно и в каких случаях? В данном случае всегда *НЕ* пишется отдельно?

Answer (score 6):

«**Не знаю**» пишется в два слова всегда, существительное ***незнание*** пишется слитно; может Вы это имели ввиду.

Answer (score 5):

Не с глаголами пишется раздельно. В вашем случае только раздельно! Подробнее здесь: http://www.lingvotech.com/neverb